# Order by occurrences of tags in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I've been stuck the last couple of days with this problem. I have the users' tags (`user_tags`) in one table and the articles in another table (`crawler_results`), and I'm trying to sort the articles so the ones which contain the most tags are placed at first.

How do you do that?
This is my code:

```
    SELECT content
    FROM crawler_results articles
    INNER JOIN user_newspapers un
    ON un.newspaper_id = articles.newspaper_id
    WHERE un.user_id = '$user_id'
```

I somehow have to join the `user_tags` table which consists of:

```
tag and user_id
```

EDIT:
Lets say the user wants to find articles with these tags: #stack and #overflow. The articles that have the most of these tags are displayed first. So an article that says: "Stack overflow is great" is ranked higher than just: "overflow is great". And tags can be reused, for instance: "overflow, overflow, overflow" counts as 3.
I want to sort the articles so the ones that contain the most tags are first.

How is this achieved? I have four tables: crawler_results (where I store the articles), newspapers (where I store the newspapers), user_newspapers (where I have newspaper_id and user_id) and user_tags (where I have the tag and user_id).

Do I need to make a separate table that stores all the words from the articles or can this be done with a sql query?

I really appreciate your help!

Comment: Try simplifying your question.  Your question mentions two tables.  Your query has five tables.  That makes it really hard to follow what you are doing and what you really want.

Comment: There appears to be no relationship between articles and tags! And there's a column called id which appears to serve no purpose!

Comment: I've tried explaining myself more clearly now. Have a look at the updated question.

Comment: As i understand the situation, you want to check the `crawler_results.content` in order to count the number of tag occurrences in it. And every user has a specific list of tags that are stored in table `user_tags`, right?

Comment: Exactly! How is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

If you just have to sort your query using the number of tags related, try this query:

```
SELECT title
    , c.name AS category
    , img_src
    , n.name AS newspaper_name
    , crawler_results.id AS id
    , crawler_results.content AS content
FROM crawler_results
INNER JOIN newspapers n ON n.id = crawler_results.newspaper_id
INNER JOIN categories c ON c.id = crawler_results.category
INNER JOIN user_newspapers un ON un.newspaper_id = n.id
INNER JOIN (SELECT ut.user_id
                ,COUNT(ut.tag) AS nb_tags
            FROM user_tags ut
            GROUP BY ut.user_id) t ON t.user_id = un.user_id
INNER JOIN user_categories uc ON uc.category_id = c.id
WHERE img_src != ''
    AND char_length(content) > 750
    AND active = '1'
    AND un.user_id = '$user_id'
GROUP BY title
ORDER BY category ASC, t.nb_tags DESC
```

If the result is not what you expect, try to clarify your question and eventually provide some example of data you're expecting.

Hope this will help.

Comment: Hi Joël Salamin.Thanks for the quick reply! Unfortunately the query doesn't do exactly what I wanted. I want to sort the articles so the ones that contain the most tags from my user_tags table are showed first. 

An example:

Comment: @MathiasLund is this query returning the expected resut? If not, can you provide the table structures, data samples and the expected result? I based my answer on the provided info, assuming the your query was running correctly and just needed this additional sorting condition

Comment: Salamin
lets say the user wants to find articles with these tags: #stack and #overflow. The articles that have the most of these tags are displayed first. So an article that says: "Stack overflow is great" is ranked higher than just: "overflow is great". And tags can be reused, for instance: "overflow, overflow, overflow" counts as 3.

Comment: It doesn't return the expected result unfortunately. It doesn't really change anything :(

Comment: I genuinely appreciate your help

Comment: With the provided info, there is absolutely no link between articles and tags! I don't know how you want to get the expected result... My query doesn't change the result, the only difference may be on the sorting

Comment: I've posted a new question:

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26287333/mysql-order-by-tag-occurrence-group-by

Comment: Ok i'll have a look at your new question, you can close this one if useless