# mysql order by tag occurrence group by

Tags: mysql

I'm not sure if this question has been answered somewhere else on this site, but I struggle to explain my problem in words.
Here it is:
What i'm trying to do is to order the articles in crawler_results by the tags that the user has chosen. So the more a tag occurs in an article (the bigger the count_tags), the higher in the hierarchy it is.

I have 4 tables: crawler_results (where I store the articles), tags (where I store tag names), article_tags (where I store tag_id and number of occurrence of tag), and user_tags (where I store user_id and tag_id).

I've tried with:

```
      SELECT cr.id, title, count_tags, t.tag
      FROM crawler_results cr
      INNER JOIN article_tags at
      ON cr.id = at.article_id
      INNER JOIN tags t
      ON t.id = at.tag_id
      INNER JOIN user_tags ut
      ON ut.tag_id = at.tag_id
      AND user_id = '$user_id'
      ORDER BY count_tags DESC
```

This query displays the articles sorted by count_tags, but unfortunately it does so with all of the tags that the article contain. For instance if an article is like this: "Stackoverflow overflow is awesome!" and the user has chosen "stack" and "overflow" as tags, "overflow" should be the only tag that the query looks at as it appears more than "stack".

I have a feeling it has something to do with GROUP BY - am I right? I just don't know how it works.

Thanks in advance!
Please let me know if you need more info.

EDIT:
Here are my tables:

crawler_results:

```
       | id         | title       | content      |
       |:-----------|------------:|:------------:|
       | 1          | Some title  | Some content |
       | 2          | Other title | Other content|
```

tags:

```
       | id         | tag         | 
       |:-----------|------------:|
       | 1          | Some tag    |
       | 2          | Other tag   |
```

article_tags:

```
       | id         | tag_id      | article_id   | count_tags   |
       |:-----------|------------:|:------------:|:------------:|
       | 1          | 1           | 1            | 5            |
       | 2          | 2           | 2            | 10           |
       | 3          | 1           | 2            | 8            |
```

user_tags:

```
       | id         | user_id     | tag_id       |
       |:-----------|------------:|:------------:|
       | 1          | 1           | 1            |
       | 2          | 1           | 2            |
```

Comment: See REPLACE and LENGTH

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL function to get count of how many times string appears in column?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3031526/sql-function-to-get-count-of-how-many-times-string-appears-in-column)

Comment: I have the count of occurrence of tag in the article, now I simply need to order them by this occurrence :)

Comment: Well, if you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: Hi Strawberry, I'm unsure how to use sqlfiddle, but I've updated my question with my db tables :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the query that seems to return the expected result:

```
SELECT cr.id
    , cr.title
    , SUM(CASE
           WHEN ut.tag_id IS NOT NULL THEN at.count_tags
           ELSE 0
          END) AS matching_tags
FROM crawler_results cr
INNER JOIN article_tags at ON cr.id = at.article_id
LEFT JOIN user_tags ut ON ut.tag_id = at.tag_id
                         AND user_id = '$user_id'
GROUP BY cr.id, cr.title
ORDER BY matching_tags DESC
```

I just added a `GROUP BY` clause in order to count the number of tags for each article and then I sort the result descending.

Hope this will help.

Comment: Hi Joël Salamin! Don't you need to replace "AND" with "WHERE" in order to only get the tags that the user has chosen? Because I tested your code and it returns all tags, not only the tags that user has chosen. I tried with WHERE instead but that doesn't work either - it returns the lowest count_tags instead of the highest. Btw the occurrence of the tags has already been counted, so no need for COUNT(ut.tag_id), simply just: at.count_tags

Comment: @MathiasLund Thank you for the additional info. I didn't notice that there already is a column called `count_tags` in one of your table, that may cause a problem with my `ORDER BY` clause... Except this point, my query seems to be correct because you're looking for the number of tags defined by the user in order to sort your result. The article having the most matching tags are on the top and the articles with no correspondance are on the bottom of the result (I edited my query to apply the correct sort condition)

Comment: The query is sorted by number of rows, and not by count_tags. I prefer if the rows would be sorted by count_tags as it already has the occurrence of tags in an article. It counts how many times "tag_id" occurs in "article_id".

Comment: Ok I used the count function in order to count the number of correspondances between user tags and article tags, I thought it was the info you were looking for

Comment: I am, I just already have the number of occurrences of tag in article_id (count_tags). I insert the occurrence with php, so I only need to order the articles by the ones that have the most tag occurrence :)

Comment: You do some part of the logic on the PHP side, I wasn't aware about that. But your count_tags is the number of occurrences for one specific user? How make you the distinction between the différent users?

Comment: no it's not occurrences for specific users. I have a script that counts the tags in the articles and inserts into article_tags: tag_id and count_tags. For instance if I have 2 tags in "tags" table: "stack" and "overflow" and I have an article that sounds like this: "stack, stack, stack overflow is awesome" it would insert the tag_id of "stack" with count_tags = 3. And with "overflow" it would insert count_tags equal to 1. Hope this makes sense :)

Comment: I edited my query in order to return the sum of matching tags (the sum takes only in account the count_tags if the user has this tag in its list). Hope this is what you are looking for